# Не повторяется вводимый символ на клавиатуре

Tags: windows, windows-7

Непонятный глюк с клавиатурой на Windows 7. При задержке нажатой клавиши, водимый символ не повторяется. Попытки повторно нажимать клавишу тоже ни к чему не приводят, клавиша подряд нажимается только один раз, в остальные разы реакции нету никакой.
Все это наблюдается для всех клавиш, включая функциональные, Win и т.д.
Замена клавиатуры и обновление драйверов проблему не решают.

Например, что бы набрать "аа", нажимаем "а", "стрелка вправо", "а". А что бы удалить два символа подряд - "BackSpase", "стрелка влево", "стрелка вправо", "BackSpase".

Answer (score 1):

Если я не ошибаюсь это сработало залипание клавиш.Посмотрите следующее **Пуск ->Панель управление -> Центр специальных возможностей -> Облегчение работы с клавиатурой.** Может быть там и найдете решение на свою проблему.Но сам никогда не сталкивался с выше упомянутой проблемой.